# Macro to convert 'multi-line' text to 'single-line' (remove line breaks?)

Tags: line-breaking

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\def\myMultiLineText{%
Line One Line One \\ %
Line Two Line Two \\ %
Line Three Line Three \\ %
Line Four Line Four  %
}

\begin{document}

Here is multi-line: \myMultiLineText ...

\end{document}
```

In the document, I'd like to insert something like:

```
Here is single-line: \doSingleLine{\myMultiLineText} ...
```

... where the `\doSingleLine{}` macro would basically remove the line-breaks (`\\`) from the text stored in `\myMultiLineText` (so its contents would be rendered on a single line).

Could someone provide an example of such a macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\newcommand\doSingleLine[1]
    {\let\normalnewline=\\
     \let\\=\relax
     #1%
     \let\\=\normalnewline}
```

**EDIT**: As pointed by egreg, this does not take care of the optional argument of `\\`. Here is an alternative implementation that handles `\\*` and `\\[10pt]`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblestar
    {\futurelet\@let@token\@dogobblestar}

\def\@dogobblestar
    {\let\next=\relax
     \ifx\@let@token*%
        \def\next{\@gobble}%
     \else\ifx\@let@token[%
         \def\next{\@gobbleoptional}%
     \fi\fi
     \next}

\def\@gobbleoptional[#1]{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\doSingleLine[1]
    {\let\normalnewline=\\
     \let\\=\gobblestar
     #1%
     \let\\=\normalnewline}
```

Note that one cannot directly use `\@ifstar` as it will gobble the space at `\\`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, @Aditya - it seems to work fine! Cheers!

Comment: Beware that this will fail if the optional argument to ``\\`` or its *-form is used.

Comment: @egreg: See the modified answer.

Answer (score 2):

put it into a `\mbox`

```
\mbox{\myMultiLineText}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, @Herbert - however, since [the `\makebox` command creates a box to contain the text specified](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#makebox), if the text lines are a little longer (just edited the OP, so the example shows that), then `\mbox` will create just a single unbreakable line... Cheers!