# PDF Metadata - Macro to extract (typeset) 'plain text' from a command?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, metadata

I apologize in advance as I am yet to accept some answers to my previous questions; but I'll dare ask this one, as it is somewhat of a showstopper - consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[fixpdftex,cmyk,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\myauthors}{Author 1 \\ Author 2 \\ {\color{lightgray}Author 3}}

\hypersetup{pdftitle=My Title, pdfauthor=\myauthors, pdfsubject=My Subject, pdfkeywords=} 

\begin{document}

\noindent\myauthors

\end{document}
```

Here I get the `\myauthors` typeset exactly as I want them (the "Author 3" is lightgray) - however, in the PDF properties, the Author metadata shows: "`Author 1  Author 2  lightgrayAuthor 3`" - that is, the "lightgray" in `\color{lightgray}` of `\myauthors` ends up as text for the `pdfauthor` attribute.

I was wandering - is there some sort of a macro, that would "extract" the typeset "plain text" (that is, only those characters that are typeset) - so I could write, say:

```
\hypersetup{... pdfauthor=\getPlainText{\myauthors}, pdfsubject=...}
```

... and get "`Author 1  Author 2  Author 3`" as PDF author metadata?

---

*Alternatively, I was thinking something along the approach in [Macro to convert 'multi-line' text to 'single-line' (remove line breaks?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29754/macro-to-convert-multi-line-text-to-single-line-remove-line-breaks) - that is, use macros like:*

```
\def\pastauth#1{\color{lightgray}#1}
\def\npastauth#1{#1}
\newcommand{\myauthors}{Author 1 \\ Author 2 \\ \pastauth{Author 3}}
```

... and then somehow define a `\getPlainText`, where the `\pastauth` would be temporarily `\let` to `\npastauth` (thus avoiding `\color{lightgray}` altogether) - but I cannot get anything with this... I also tried redefining `\color` with `\@gobbleone`, but that doesn't work either

Comment: I removed some parts of your code that weren't relevant to the question. Please try to do so yourself before posting a question, keep everything simple (which sometimes isn't so simple itself `:)`).

Comment: Thanks for that, @doncherry - it's just that sometimes I use these snippets to start new examples, and so I like to have some arguments I usually forget standing around `:)` Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the

```
\texorpdfstring{<TeX string>}{<PDF string>}
```

macro to define a separate TeX and/or PDF string:

```
\newcommand{\myauthors}{Author 1 \\ Author 2 \\ \texorpdfstring{\color{lightgray}Author 3}{Author 3}}
```

The following is a view of the Document Properties using Adobe Acrobat:

[image: PDF meta data]

So, your `<TeX string>` defines the colour, while your `<PDF string>` uses a "plain text" version (void of `\color`).

This is supported by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and is also usually associated with math contents in sectional headings, which end up in the PDF bookmarks (which is text-based). For more on this "replacement macro", see the [`hyperref` documentation (HTML version)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-160004.1.2).

Comment: Fantastic @Werner - many thanks for this answer! Cheers!