# Stripping newlines from \@title

Tags: line-breaking

I'm writing the document title to a file using the command `\immediate\write\myfile{\@title}`, but it fails if the title contains newlines `\\`.

How can I strip newlines (or even better any kind of formatting, `~` included) from `\@title`? I've tried solutions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35885/28685) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29755/28685), but without success.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: Many more things will fail this way: accented letters, for instance. What ``\\`` should be replaced with?

Comment: @egreg Newlines should be replaced with a long hypen (the same generated by `--`). If it fails with accented letters would be a problem too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many more things will fail with `\immediate\write`.

I suggest getting an “immediate” version of `\protected@write`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% get a copy of `\protected@write
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% patch the copy to add \immediate
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
\makeatother

\newwrite\titlefile


\begin{document}

\author{A. Uthor}
\title{A title with \'accent \\ and new~line}

\immediate\openout\titlefile=\jobname.title
\makeatletter
\protected@iwrite\titlefile{\def\\{--}\def~{ }}{\@title}
\immediate\closeout\titlefile
\makeatother

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110885/4427 for further information.

With this setup, the file `\jobname.title` will contain

```
A title with \'accent -- and new line
```

Comment: Tha solution is excellent, and it would be perfect if only it could save accented letters directly to file.

Comment: @mmj That possibility depends on several factors. With `pdflatex` and UTF-8 it's going to be quite difficult.

Comment: Would it be possible with XeTeX or other TeX processor?

Comment: @mmj Yes, with XeTeX or LuaTeX you can input directly the accented character and no transformation is performed.